# Where may I find passwords for fictitious Sandbox Accounts that PayPal creates automatically on its Developer site registration?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

PayPal [says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/):

> When you register as a PayPal developer on the Developer site, the Sandbox automatically creates a **Business test account** for you (such as `pp.merch01-facilitator@example.com`) and its associated NVP/SOAP API test credentials. A **default Personal account** (such as `pp.merch01-buyer@example.com`) is also created automatically

That's great from PayPal, but where are their passwords? These accounts are pretty much useless without passwords. Have PayPal devs really forgot to include passwords for those accounts? Because there is neither links nor options nor fields nor anything to get or assign passwords for them.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For the test accounts you already have, if you go to [Sandbox Test accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) you will see a list of accounts. Click any and you will see 2 options "Profile" | "Notifications". If you click on Profile you will see the option to change the password.

PD: From the image you show, click any account to see the "Profile" option. In there you can change the password (without inputting the old one)

Answer (score 1):

Try the password for your regular PayPal account. You can always just create new test accounts from the Sandbox test site. If you create new accounts from there, it will let you enter your own password for the accounts.

Comment: I know that. But why do they create default test accounts without passwords and without possibility to assign them passwords? I looks silly and like a mockery

Comment: You can assign them passwords... please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having just had this issue myself, the existing answers are no longer correct as of August 2019. PayPal no longer gives you the option to set a sandbox account's password when you first create it, nor does clicking on an account give you a list of options.

Instead, there's now a menu handle in the rightmost column (circled below). Hover over it, then select "View/Edit Account". This will open a popup window listing, among other things, the "System Generated Password" of the account. You can also change the account's password from here, if you so desire.

[image]